# intterrupt that checks if a key was pressed and reads which key it was

Tags: assembly, x86-16, bios

As part of my school project, I am trying to build a snake game. I've managed to draw a pixel and make it move using the a,w,s,d keys as arrows so far. My problem is that instead of my snake moving and changing direction only when a key is pressed, my snake waits for a key press (meaning pausing my whole program) and only then continues to move. From my understanding, I've been using the wrong interrupt (int 16h\00) and I would like to know what other interrupts I can use instead.

I've tried int 16h \01 but all it did was changed direction once and then continued moving in that direction.

this is the part of my code that is in charge of changing my pixel's placement:

```
      proc check_press


        ; check for a key press
            mov ah,0
            int 16h 


        ;check what key
        check_key:
            cmp al,119
            je down
            cmp al,97
            je left
            cmp al,100
            je right
            cmp al,115
            je up
            cmp al, 27
            je escape

        up:
        inc [y]
        jmp bye

        left:
        dec [x]
        jmp bye

        down:
        dec [y]
        jmp bye

        right:
        inc [x]
        jmp bye

        escape:
        mov ah, 0
        mov al, 2
        int 10h 

        bye:

    ret 
   endp check_press
```

I would thank anybody with any idea or even if someone has ever written a snake game in assembly it would be a lot of help

Comment: Normally you want the snake to move on its own, not to move one block left when you press left.  So you should be setting a direction variable instead of modifying `x` or `y`.

Answer (score 3):

> I've tried int 16h \01 but all it did was changed direction once and then continued moving in that direction.

[Ralph Brown's interrupt list](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int.htm) contains a description of nearly all MS-DOS and BIOS interrupts.

The description about `int 16h`, function `01` on this page says:

> ...
>   Return:
>   ZF set if no keystroke available
>   ZF clear if keystroke available
>   AH = BIOS scan code
>   AL = ASCII character
>
> Note: If a keystroke is present, it is **not removed** from the keyboard buffer
>   ...

This means that the function will return a value in AX that represents the value that will be returned when you call function `00` later.

Suppose you press the keys "A", "B", "C" and "D" and you don't call any `int 16h` function. Later you call function `00` four times. In this case you expect that "A" is returned the first time, "B" the second time, "C" the third time and "D" the fourth time.

If you call function `01` before calling function `00` the first time, the function will always return "A" (although you pressed "B", "C" and "D" later) because function `00` will return "A" when it will be called the next time.

If you don't call function `00`, function `01` will return "key 'A' pressed" forever.

You **must** call `int 16h`, function `00` if function `01` returned `ZF=clear`:

```
  mov ah, 1
  int 16h
  jz noKeyPressed
  mov ah, 0
  int 16h
  ; AX contains information about the key pressed
  ...
noKeyPressed:
  ...
```

Comment: Hey, wanted to inform that you helprd a-lot!!

Comment: Thanks so much to everyone

Answer (score 2):

Normally you want the snake to move on its own, not to move one block left when you press left.  So **you should be setting a direction variable instead of modifying `x` or `y`**.  Your whole design is built around this press-to-move behaviour, so you'll have to rewrite a lot of it.

You probably want to use non-blocking keyboard reads to check for keyboard input right before a snake update.  Or hook the keyboard interrupt and update a direction variable from there.

You can use `hlt` to sleep until the next interrupt (e.g. timer or keyboard), then wake up and see if it's time to redraw the snake.

Another option *might* be drawing the snake from a timer interrupt, but doing a lot of work in an interrupt handler is bad.